# application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: called more than once.How to avoid?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I have an application, that uses Remote/Push notifications.

Background mode for remote notification is used, and everything works as expected.Application wakes up and takes all needed data from server.

But if Push notification alert  is not cleared from Notification Center, and user click it `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` method will be called again, and that means it will send new request to server, and that is undesirable behaviour.

First option is to check application state, but that causing me a problems, when application is in suspended.I have to do something like code below, but this doesn't work for me:

```
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive || [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

    }
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState  == UIApplicationStateInactive){

    }
```

Second option is, whether there is a way to clear alerts from Notification Center when user opens application, but I cannot find way to do it.

So is there a way to avoid second call  of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` method?

Comment: in which situations did you encounter 2 calls of the method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:`?

Comment: Very simple: If you have remote notification with "content-available" : 1 device wakes up (not every time) and execute application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: .If your notification is also interactive (alert,badge and sound) and user clicks alert application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: is called again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send unique ID in your APNS message, then filter second call by remebering that ID - either in your app's temporary collection ( then you are called second time if you kill app between APNS message was received and is clicked ) or persistent storage ( to avoid second call in any case ).

Comment: I think, that this is only option.

Comment: Rightly said, currently this is the only option, but I am interested in any unique id which apple provides for each notification so that we can compare if same notification is processed again in *didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:* method.